# Euclid's Proposition 6 Book I proof by circle

Tags: euclidean-geometry

Euclides proves proposition 6 in book I using a *reductio ad absurdum* proof assuming that line AB is less than line AC.

Couldn't we just draw a circle with center A and distance B, and by definition 15 prove that AB = AC, as described in the following figure?

[image: proof by circle]

You can see the proposition in this link http://aleph0.clarku.edu/~djoyce/java/elements/bookI/propI6.htm.

Comment: Could you give the complete proof that you are proposing?

Comment: Yes, one moment.

Comment: Ok, there it is.

Comment: But you need show that if a triangle have two angles equals THEN the opposite sides are equal.

If you use a circle for show $AB$ is equal to $AC$ you not saying nothing about the angles.

Comment: So, what exactly is my proof stating? That this particular triangle has sides AB = AC?

Comment: Then it seems to me that I don't know yet how to build mathematical proofs. I should use that information about the angles and build upon that to arrive at my conclusion?

Comment: You are trying prove, if a triangle have to side equals then the opposite angles are equals.

Comment: @felipegf The proposition is with the form $p \implies q$, but Euclides use the equivalence $\lnot q \implies \lnot p$